# Windows 8 partition mounting

Tags: mount, files, windows-8

How can I browse windows 8 system files with Ubuntu? Whenever I try to access it it says error 14 and does not let me browse the files like in windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 uses a [modified hibernate to shutdown/boot more quickly](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/what-is-fast-startup-windows-8-disable-it/). If you need write access to the partition you should turn off the fast startup feature. If you write something while windows is in hibernate bad things will happen.

If read access is sufficient you can mount the partition like this:

```
 sudo mount -t ntfs -r /dev/sda2 /mnt/ntfs
```

where `/dev/sda2` is the ntfs partition (`sudo fdisk -l` will give you an overview of your partitions) and `/mnt/ntfs` is the folder where the partition should be mounted (make sure the dir exists first)